# Engineering not working on Mobile app

Tags: discussion

So all I get is "Request failed. Tap to retry."

Quit the app and gone back in but same thing, however it works for the other 7 sites I use regularly... Works on the laptop though.

Any ideas?

If I have the sort as "newest" then it fails with "Request failed. Tap to retry."

BUT if I select "Active" as the sort, it works...

Comment: Possibly related on MSE: [Many API requests to /questions with filter parameters are failing with status code 400 errors](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378964/241919) (mobile apps use the same API)

Comment: Note: if you're talking about the official mobile apps, they are no longer officially supported (or even still available for download on the Apple or Google Play app stores). [See this FAQ on Meta Stack Exchange for more info.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348075/335251)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just so the question has an answer to get it out of the queue:

All is now working fine, so all good.